# How to run standalone script from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I had a google sheet with bounded script that was working fine but needed to be run with standalone script so that other people can use it. I made a copy of the spreadsheet then cut out all the bounded script and past into a standalone script. I have turned one the sheet and task api in the standalone sheet and saved the version.

Then I went to the bounded script and included the unbounded script as a library.

What else do I have to do to see and use the codes in the library.

Comment: Don't mean to be pedantic, but have you read the [documentation on Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Comment: @Tedinoz I did read the documentation and used it to link to the library. I got up to sep 2 in using the library. It opens a separate browser showing the names of all the functions in the library. But still can't work out how to use them

Comment: OK got a bit further code now running but has some errors I need to work through

Comment: previously missed step 7